# Updating Updaing Multi-Dim Array deletes data from array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a pretty basic PHP Shopping Cart that has been working fine on my live site.

I recently backed up and installed the site on a localhost and I find that my code is executing differently on the localhost. I have been trying to figure out why for days. In desperation I am seeking help.

The code is to grab the $_POST['qty'] and $_POST['spit_qty] entries from the cart and update the SHOPPING_CART array.

The code in question:

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])){
   if ((isset($_POST['items_qty'])) || (isset($_POST['split_qty'])))
      {
          foreach ($_POST['items_qty'] as $itemID => $new_qty)
              {
                  $_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'][$itemID]['qty'] = $new_qty;
              }
                   foreach ($_POST['split_qty'] as $itemID => $new_split_qty)
                       {
                           $_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'][$itemID]['split_qty'] = $new_split_qty;
                       }
                   foreach ($_POST['items_qty'] as $itemID => $qty)
                       {
                           if (($qty == 0) && ($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'][$itemID]['split_qty'] == 0))
                       {
                           unset($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'][$itemID]);
                    }
                }
            }
            header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            $return_page = $_SESSION['return_page']; 
}
```

Here is my Cart array with two items in it.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 22314 - BURGER SLIDER W/BUN ANGUS CKD
            [price] => 62.30
            [qty] => 1
            [split_qty] => 0
            [split_price] => 0
            [pack] => 72/2.2 oz
            [bf] => 72
            [brk] => 0.0000
            [cw] => N
            [page] => products?group=0055&cat=BEE
            [cat] => BEE
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 22365 - BURGERS 4OZ FULLY COOKED
            [price] => 54.00
            [qty] => 1
            [split_qty] => 0
            [split_price] => 0
            [pack] => 1/10 lb
            [bf] => 1
            [brk] => 0.0000
            [cw] => N
            [page] => products?group=0055&cat=BEE
            [cat] => BEE
        )
)
```

I update the qty's in the Cart.

When I look at the $_POST['items_qty'] data:

Key : 0 - Value: 2
Key : 1 - Value: 2

So the ['qty'] data is looking OK, but when I look at the SHOPPING_CART array after the Qty has been updated, qty's are OK but all of the other elements of the array have been deleted.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 2
        )

)
```

I don't understand why updating the array deletes all of the elements that are not being updated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd recommend adding a `var_dump($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART']` statement right before you start the loops and see what it contains...my guess is it's empty for some reason. Likely some issue with $_SESSION not persisting correctly on localhost.

Comment: Also make sure you comment out the `header` call temporarily so that you can see the var_dump results.

Comment: I do have var_dumps setup before and after the loop, as far as I can tell, the $_SESSION seems to work properly, I have several other parameters that I save using $_SESSION and they all persist through the update cycle.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back here. In the end it turned out that my php interperter Sourcer was the problem, I had to un-install, clean and then reinstall the plug in. Then everything started to work as it should.